# php mysql beginner echo MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

i want to count row and print php echo. But when i echo the query it show: Resource id #5. But it must show only number 5.

```
<?php 
$db=require "script_database/connect.php"; 
$query="select count(name) from selection where salary>2000 and job='teacher' ";
        $key=mysql_query($query);
        echo $key;
         if(key>0)
        {

        echo "no row found";

        }
 ?>
```

Comment: You want to echo your `query` or the `records` ? Also **never use mysql_* as it is depreciated**

Comment: you don't add a require to a variable..

Comment: Do you want to display the count of rows affected or  the count of names?

Comment: @sulthanallaudeen it's deprecated. I can't say what effect this has had on its intrinsic value

Comment: @Strawberry I believe we can't utilize on php 7, Isn't it ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen That's a feature of deprecation, not depreciation

Comment: @Strawberry Ah, it was a typo, and now i am clear from [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/45295) :)

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_query` will return the resource of the executed query, not the data. You have to fetch it -

```
    $query="select count(name) from selection where salary>2000 and job='teacher' ";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $key = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $key['count(name)'];
```

> mysql is deprecated now. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

**Return**

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data.
>
> Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a SELECT statement or mysql_affected_rows() to find out how many rows were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.
>
> mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.

Comment: Would 'count(name)' be returned? Never tried, I would assign the count to a variable: `select count(name) as count from selection where salary>2000 and job='teacher'` .. Then echo $key['count']  -- Still doesn't get around he assigned $db to an include, and thinks that if the query returns > 0 then nothing was found..

Comment: If you dont use any alias then `count(name)` will be returned in this case.

Comment: Learn something new every day. I always have added an alias. Up-voted your answer for your extra efforts by adding the doc info. I still think he needs to fix his `$db=require "script_database/connect.php"`

Comment: but i cannot say your answer use full why??

Answer (score -3):

You may have to use `mysql_num_rows`

```
$query = "Select * from selection where salary>2000 and job='teacher'"

echo mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: Selecting all fields for a simple count?

Comment: Down voted for 2 reasons. 1) Your answer was already answered by another member. 2) You shouldn't use `SELECT *`, especially since the OP specifically declares his columns.